# Button not responding.. JavaScript not expanding

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm new to programming and am having some difficulty. I do not understand why, but my button text is not resizing properly when the screen size is adjusted. The overarching div container is not resizing to accomodate the button properly either.. and the button was taking two clicks to expand the text, but now it is not expanding at all and I am not sure what I changed.

I am a beginner and this is my first time implementing javascript into html/css so keep that in mind with complex answers, I may not understand right away.

The codepen link with full code is here:

https://codepen.io/rachel-campbell/pen/xvLxLK

```
#collapseMe {
display:inline-block;
width: 100%;
padding: 2rem;
font-size: 2vw;
font-weight: bolder;
box-shadow: 0 0.3em 0.3em #ccc;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
float:center;

}
button:hover {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You can provide the full code here using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552). Of course, even better would be a [mcve] that whittles down your code to just enough to show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why script/button wasn't working

I just want to point out what mistakes you made to help you understand what went wrong with your code.

In your codepen, there's are javascript files being referenced to non-existing files.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newmarket.css" />`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="newmarket.js"></script>`

You need to remember, files you place in code playgrounds like codepen, jsfiddle, etc need to be hosted somewhere. This missing javascript files will make the rest of your javascript fail.

2nd, always check the developer's console. Use f12 to fire it up, you will see all the errors that will come up. By just using the developers console. I picked up a couple of problems that causes your script and therefore your button to not work.

When you use jQuery and write your selectors, make sure non-variables or strings are enclosed with double quotes or single quotes (but jQuery encourages the use of double quotes for strings).

Your `$(body)` is causing error because body is not being declared as variable so it is supposed to be a string. It should be `$("body")`.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

Also, you've written `y.style.margin-bottom="3rem";` when it should be `y.style.marginBottom="3rem";` so 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_marginbottom.asp

#### About the Button text not resizing properly

As for the button text size not resizing properly, you should look at Devin's answer about css.

#### As for the button needing 2 clicks before it collapses the hidden div

You are hiding the div using `hidden=true` attribute, however in your script it checks if the it has `style="display:none;"` those are two different things. So just add `style="display:none` in your `<div id="collapsable" hidden=true>` and remove `hidden=true` so it becomes:

`<div id="collapsable" style="display:none;">`

**You should see all the fixes here:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VozLPg

Comment: Thank you so much! This and Devin's answer help a ton. I'm going to try these solutions out and apply the tips to future projects also.

Answer (score -1):

Your #collapseMe id as `font-size: 2vw;` which gives you consistent smooth resizing. However, since the button is inside a card with margins, this doesn't make sense at smaller screen widths. So using `vw` unit as your font size is really not a good choice here, its better if the text is in a container that is always full width.

In addition, the bootstrap .btn class has `white-space: nowrap;` which is preventing the text from wrapping.

I would suggest using a static font size - maybe 1.4 or so? as well as over-riding the `white-space` property like so:

```
#collapseMe.btn {
  white-space: unset;
}
```

As a side note, since it sounds like you are in the beginning stages of learning, I would suggest avoiding jquery and bootstrap in favor of using modern css (with flex and grid) and vanilla javascript. This will help you learn the basics better and help you become a better developer.

Comment: thank you so much! I had no idea about the bootstrap btn class having that set.. I actually added it to try and help the situation. This is very helpful and educational, I really appreciate the insight.